# ESLint, Computed object property names and destructuring when removing properties from an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, destructuring

Is there a syntax that allows me to remove a key from an object literal, without naming an unnecessary variable for the object value?

I'm currently using de-structuring because I can't mutate the original array, and this seemed like the nicest approach:

```
let productsById = { 'abc': { 'name': 'fred', 'id': 'abc' } }

function deleteFromProducts(idToDelete, productsById) {
  const {
        [idToDelete]: deletedProduct,
        ...remainingProductsById
  } = productsById;
  return remainingProductsById;
}
```

However, 'deletedProduct' gets flagged by the 'no-unused-vars' ESLint rule, as it's not necessary.

I realise I can add _ or something and exclude it from the ESLint rule but was just wondering if there was a nicer syntax I was missing.

Comment: Wait. What do you need to do? can't you simply `delete productsById[idToDelete]`?...

Comment: @briosheje I can't mutate the original array (this is in a redux reducer).

Comment: Euh okay, so what about using `.splice` or `.slice` instead?

Comment: It's an object literal rather than an array (it's being treated as a map with a string key)

Comment: @JamesCrowley How about deep clone the productsById object and then delete clonedObject[idToDelete] and return the clonedObject